# JQuery - Looping through the list of employees in employee directory

Tags: jquery

I have embedded a javascript/jquery in the xsl page. The javascript code iterates through the available employee list in the employee directory of sharepoint page. When a particular field matches a value, then a necessary action is taken on the page to display at the top.

```
Below is the code for that:

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> 
    <![CDATA[ 
    <!-- JavaScript injected by peoplesearch.xsl. This script waits for the peoplesearch output to render,
         then  -->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
    // List of titles held by dept/lab heads. This will be used to
    // identify those heads and move them to the first position in the
    // people list
    var managerTitles = ["A", "B"];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var personIndex = 0;

        // Iterate each person
        $('.psrch-FullResult').each(function(Index){                
        // Get that person's job title

                var jobTitle = $('#JobTitleField', this).text();

                // If the job title is in the list of managerTitles, make this person the first in the list if
                // they're not aready first
                if($.inArray(jobTitle, managerTitles) >= 0) {
                    // If they're not first in the list, move them there"
                    if(personIndex > 0) {
                        // Move the manager to first
                        $(this).insertBefore($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
                    }

                    // Insert a block div to create a line break after the manager
                    $("<div style='display:block;clear:both;'></div>").insertAfter($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
                     //removed this line due to need for multiple heads of a dept -- return false;//Leave the .each iterator
                }

            personIndex++;

    });
    });
    </script> 
    ]]> 
    </xsl:text>

Below is the field declaration in sharepoint 2010


  <xsl:if test="$hasjt">
                      <li id="JobTitleField">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/jobtitle" />
                      </li>
                    </xsl:if>


But when I try to fetch the value using the code
```

**var jobTitle = $('#JobTitleField', this).text();**

it always retrieves the first value only and does it not change for all the employees. But the looping is happening perfect. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: fairly simple...you can't repeat ID's in a page...they are unique by defintiion...switch to class

Comment: <xsl:if test="$hasjt">
                      <li class="JobTitleField">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/jobtitle" />
                      </li>
                    </xsl:if>

should I try this and use var jobTitle = $('#JobTitleField', this).text();

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is happening because you are selecting the value by `ID` in a loop here -

`var jobTitle = $('#JobTitleField', this).text();`

You should instead use a `class` or dynamically generated `ID` or `this` to refer the current object in the loop.

See, if this works -

Change the ID `JobTitleField` to class and then  (or can add a new class and use it)

`var jobTitle = $('.JobTitleField', this).text();`

Comment: I tried

<xsl:if test="$hasjt">
                      <li class="JobTitleField">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/jobtitle" />
                      </li>
                    </xsl:if>

and used var jobTitle = $('.JobTitleField', this).text();

But still the jobTitle is "". Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use class and then use  jquery find()..

`var jobTitle = $(this).find(li.JobTitleField).text();`

Comment: var jobTitle = $($.find('.JobTitleField')).text();
This is retrieving all the JobTitleField values in the entire page.

But the following code is still retrieving blank.

var jobTitle = $(this).find('.JobTitleField').text();

Any suggestions to retrieve only those for that specific index and not all at a time?

Comment: What I meant was when you loop through your people search results `$('.psrch-FullResult').each(function(Index)`, `$(this)` will be each people result item and `$(this).find()` should find an element within each result item.